# Azure Pipeline - Strong named assemblies in solution

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure Pipeline that builds a Winform solution with multiple projects that are Strong signed with a PFX.

I found the following link:

https://dhvik.blogspot.com/2020/01/building-strong-named-assemblies-in.html

This is my YAML file:

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- group: 'CertPass'

steps:

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download Pfx
  name: myCertificatePfx
  inputs:
    secureFile: ventasmlcert.pfx
    
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download sni
  name: snInstallPfx
  inputs:
    secureFile: SnInstallPfx.exe    

- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    SN_INSTALL_PFX: $(snInstallPfx.secureFilePath)
    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX: $(myCertificatePfx.secureFilePath)
    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD: $(certpass)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '&"$($ENV:SN_INSTALL_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD)"'
    
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build .csproj file'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Everything works fine in the pipeline for the signing of my PFX:

[image]

But when building the solution I still get the error, but was looking that the Container where the signing was added is different from the other Containers of each project that needs to be signed.

This is the error:

> Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: ***cert.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_71452E506F1E61FB

Any clue?

Comment: You sure it's the same key? VS_KEY_71452E506F1E61FB isn't want your build lod mentions...

Comment: Yes it says that. I don’t know if I have to set any configuration in Azure Pipeljne for the host agent or something.

Comment: Seems the job is running each task in a separate container.

Comment: Yes, every job runs on its own VM. You'll need to restore the key at the start of each job that needs it.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? Please 

Comment: Because I think I only have one job, because if you see my Yaml is only one steps with multiple tasks.

Comment: That should be 1 job. For multiple jobs you'd need multiple stapes or job elements.