# Azure Pipeline - Tasks seems to run on different containers, how to make all them share same

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have the following YAML

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- group: 'CertPass'

steps:

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download Pfx
  name: myCertificatePfx
  inputs:
    secureFile: ventasmlcert.pfx
    
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download sni
  name: snInstallPfx
  inputs:
    secureFile: SnInstallPfx.exe    

- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    SN_INSTALL_PFX: $(snInstallPfx.secureFilePath)
    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX: $(myCertificatePfx.secureFilePath)
    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD: $(certpass)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '&"$($ENV:SN_INSTALL_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD)"'
    
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build .csproj file'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Because my solution has different projects that are strongly signed with a PFX certificate I have first to add the certificate to the machine. Then the solution build happens but what I saw is that the Container name for the Certificate task is different for every project that is built.

When I run the PowerShell script for the certificate the output is:

```
The key pair has been installed into the strong name CSP key container 'VS_KEY_2211CE6F0D92996F'. VS_KEY_2211CE6F0D92996F Finishing: PowerShell
```

And in the solution build task I get errors related to the PFX because it couldn't be found because every project compilation seems to be running on different containers:

**Project A error:**

```
 Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: ***cert.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_71452E506F1E61FB
```

**Project B error:**

```
 Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: ***cert.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_1789CEF560C2266D
```

So if you see the Powershell executes the certificate in a conatiner VS_KEY_2211CE6F0D92996F, then Project A is compiled in a container VS_KEY_71452E506F1E61FB and Project B in a container VS_KEY_1789CEF560C2266D

Any clue on how to make all my tasks execute in the same container?

Comment: Your supposition is incorrect: A single job (as you have here) runs on a single "server" (whether it's a VM or a container is an implementation detail that's irrelevant for this discussion). At the completion of the job, the "server" used to run the job is recycled/terminated. Every time you run the pipeline, it's a fresh environment, but the entire job will be running within the *same* environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Pipeline - Strong named assemblies in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71089176/azure-pipeline-strong-named-assemblies-in-solution)

Comment: Daniel then why I get a different container name for each task?